# Moodle select script displays incorrect role for the user

Tags: mysql, roles, moodle

The role 'Bank Employee' is not assigned to employee WILLIAM DE DIOS as seen in the screenshot accessed from Moodle.

But the script I made shows that this employee already has role of 'Bank Employee'.

Here is the script:

```
 select distinct u.username USER_NAME, u.firstname FIRST_NAME, u.lastname LAST_NAME, u. auth, 
 u.suspended, u. idnumber, u.email, u.maildisplay, r.name ROLE_NAME
 from mdl_user u
 left join mdl_role_assignments ra ON ra.userid=u.id
 left join mdl_role r ON ra.roleid = r.id
 where u.lastname like '%DE DIOS%' and u.firstname like '%WILLIAM%'
 order by lastname;
```

Help please I need to revise the script so that only the assigned role would appear.  'Bank Employee' role should not appear as seen in the Moodle module.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible the Bank Employee role was somehow assigned to the user in a context other than the system context - e.g. other contexts like course, block, user, etc.? This can lead to an entry in the role_assignments table for the Bank Employee role, but in a context that isn't the system context. This entry wouldn't appear in the screen you shared b/c that shows only users with the role for the system context.  I've seen this happen in past with unintended/old role assignments not removed from DB. Querying role_assignments using the roleid and userid may reveal this situation. Hope helpful.